# Downloading email to computer + deleting them from a server with scripts

Tags: php, email, download

I am a newbie to scripting and I am trying to get better. I was wondering if anybody knew where I could find a script to download email from my POP/IMAP email account to my computer and then delete all of the email from my email account so that I wouldn't have any email online, I would just have emails on my computer.

I looked around and I thought that the easiest way to do this would maybe be with PHP, but I'm not sure if I can do all of this with PHP, as well as the fact that I'm not that great with PHP, so I have no idea where I would start.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is with a Desktop Email Client (something like [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.getthunderbird.com/)). Simply connect via POP and set it to delete the messages from the server after download.

PHP is not for this.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Outlook or any other email client would do the trick, or am I missing something in the question?